# How to show that a solution of $L(y) = 0$ is real valed

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

In the book of *Int. to Ordinary DEs* by Coddington, at page 109 in question 5.b, it is asked that

> Let $$L(y) = y^{(n)} + a_1(x)y^{n-1} + ...+ a_n (x) y,$$ where $a_1,
>  ..., a_n$ are continuous real-valued functions on the interval $I$.
>
> **b-)**Let $\phi$ be a solution of $L(y) = 0$ satisfying $$\phi(x_0) = \alpha_1, \phi'(x_0) = \alpha_2,..., \phi^{n-1} (x_0) = \alpha_n,$$
>   where $x_0 \in I$, and $\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n$ are real constants.
>   Prove that $\phi$ is real-valued.

To show this, I need to take an arbitrary value from the the real line, and show that the image under $\phi$ is a real number, but I couldn't find a way to show that, so any help or hint is appreciated.

Comment: Since everything in the problem description is real the solution does not even know that complex numbers exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\phi =f+ig$ where $f$ and $g$ are real valued. Then $g$ is a solution of the differential given equation with the initial conditions $g(0)=0,g'(0)=0,...,g^{n-1} (0)=0$. [Just take imaginary parts in the equation $\phi^{j}(0)=\alpha_k$]. By an earlier theorem in Coddington's book this implies $g=0$ so $\phi =f$ is real valued.